# backbone view rendering twice due to binding on id change

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following code on one of my views:

```
this.model.on('change:id', this.itemIdChanged, this );

 itemIdChanged: function(){
        if(this.model.hasChanged('id')) {
            var that = this;
            this.model.fetch({
                success: function (item) {
                    that.render();
                }
            })
        } 
    },
```

and so once I changed the id of this model, then it would call render twice, once when I set the id and the other one when it is at the success block of fetch. This is very disturbing as then it calls render twice which is annoying in the eye and wasteful. How can I avoid this?

Comment: First of all, I think `if(this.model.hasChanged('id'))` is redundant. If `change:id` triggered then of course `id` has been changed right? Regarding your question, do you have another listener on this view? Perhaps one that listening to `change`? May be give us more code and we can see where the problem is. Also, it is likely to be your own error that `render` is being called twice. Why are you saying it as if it is the library fault?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a `change` event is getting triggered after your `fetch`call.  This is the expected behavior when a `fetch` call changes attributes of a model.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Cannot give you alternatives without more information on what your trying to do.

Comment: so I wanted to change the model attributes, by supplying it an id

Comment: you can pass {silent: true} then